# Android app crashing during swipe to delete recyclerview using Room database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am currently doing my #7DaysOfCodeChallenge at Udacity and implemented Swipe to delete on recyclerview which uses room database but the app crashes and nothing is deleted from the room database. Here is a link to the Actvity on github[MainActivity.Java](https://github.com/ngengesenior/Journal-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/ngenge/journal/MainActivity.java)

I cannot figure out what is wrong with it

Comment: can you show your log. I have read your code but didn't find delete code

Comment: Post your code here rather than providing a link to Github.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the problem. The problem was that I was calling an asyncTask which required a parameter and I failed to pass it.Anyways, the code is hosted on https://github.com/ngengesenior/Journal-App/